# Как вызвать функцию в php?

Tags: php, классы, функции

Создал код:

```
class Api
{
    public $breedName = 'Саванна';

    public function showBreed()
    {
        echo $this->breedName;
    }

    public function showLink()
    {
        echo "Вторая функция здесь!";
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь обратится к функции site.com/api.php/api/showBreed но получаю пустой экран. Что я делаю не так и как правильно вызвать функцию?

Спасибо!

Comment: `site.com/api.php/api/showBreed` таким образом не обращаются к методам в классах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site.com/api.php/api/showBreed` меняем на `site.com/api.php?method=showBreed`

в api.php

```
if($_GET['method'] == 'showBreed'){
 $api = new Api();
 $api->showBreed();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Чисто дополню ответ выше

```
if(isset($_GET['method'])) {
    $method = $_GET['method'];
    $api = new Api();
    if(method_exists($api,$method)) {
        $api->$method();
        exit();
    }
}

echo '404 error';
```

Вот так будет менбше ошибок